# Double Linked Lists Code Revisions

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am having some trouble making the appropriate changes from a post I made on code review. Here is the original post I made [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/195903/generic-double-linked-list/195943?noredirect=1#comment377415_195943). Specifically, I am at the point where I am revising my insertPosition function.

Previously my function was like this:

```
template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::insertPosition(int pos, const T& theData) {
    Node* prev = new Node;
    Node* current = head;
    Node* newNode = new Node;

    for(int i = 1; i < pos; i++) {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    newNode->data = theData;
    prev->next = newNode;
    newNode->next = current;
}
```

But now, from what I have been told to do was make it more like this:

```
Node* cur_node = head;
int i = 0;
while (cur_node) {
    if (i++ == pos) {
        // do the deed
    }
    cur_node = cur_node->next;
}
```

I am not sure what to write in the // do the deed part. What I have tried is this:

```
template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::insertPosition(int pos, const T& theData) {
    Node* current = head;
    int i = 0;
    while(current) {
        if(i++ == pos) {
            Node* newNode = new Node;
            newNode->data = theData;
            newNode->next = newNode->previous;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

But I do not get the code to work at all when I test it out. There are also various other things I need to change I am sure but I would like to get a second opinion of my code I have thus far.

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef DoubleLinkedLists_h
#define DoubleLinkedLists_h

template <class T>
class DoubleLinkedLists {
private:

    struct Node {
        T data;
        Node* next;
        Node* previous;
    };

    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

public:
    // Constructors
    DoubleLinkedLists() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}                  // empty constructor
    DoubleLinkedLists(DoubleLinkedLists const& value);                     // copy constructor
    DoubleLinkedLists<T>(DoubleLinkedLists<T>&& move) noexcept;            // move constuctor
    DoubleLinkedLists<T>& operator=(DoubleLinkedLists&& move) noexcept;    // move assignment operator
    ~DoubleLinkedLists();                                                  // destructor

    // Overload operators
    DoubleLinkedLists& operator=(DoubleLinkedLists const& rhs);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, DoubleLinkedLists<T> const& data) {
        data.display(str);
        return str;
    }

    // Member functions
    void swap(DoubleLinkedLists& other) noexcept;
    void createNode(const T& theData);
    void createNode(T&& theData);
    void display(std::ostream& str) const;
    void insertHead(const T& theData);
    void insertTail(const T& theData);
    void insertPosition(int pos, const T& theData);
    void deleteHead();
    void deleteTail();
    void deletePosition(int pos);
    bool search(const T& x);
};

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>::DoubleLinkedLists(DoubleLinkedLists const& value) : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {
    for(Node* loop = value->head; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        createNode(loop->data);
    }
}

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>::DoubleLinkedLists(DoubleLinkedLists<T>&& move) noexcept : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {
    move.swap(*this);
}

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>& DoubleLinkedLists<T>::operator=(DoubleLinkedLists<T> &&move) noexcept {
    move.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>::~DoubleLinkedLists() {
    while(head != nullptr) {
        deleteHead();
    }
}

template <class T>
DoubleLinkedLists<T>& DoubleLinkedLists<T>::operator=(DoubleLinkedLists const& rhs) {
    DoubleLinkedLists copy(rhs);
    swap(copy);
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::swap(DoubleLinkedLists<T>& other) noexcept {
    using std::swap;
    swap(head, other.head);
    swap(tail, other.tail);
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::createNode(const T& theData) {
    Node* newData = new Node;
    newData->data = theData;
    newData->next = nullptr;

    if(head == nullptr) {
        newData->previous = nullptr;
        head = newData;
        tail = newData;
    }
    else {
        newData->previous = tail;
        tail->next = newData;
        tail = newData;
    }
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::createNode(T&& theData) {
    Node* newData = new Node;
    newData->data = std::move(theData);
    newData->next = nullptr;

    if(head == nullptr) {
        newData->previous = nullptr;
        head = newData;
        tail = newData;
    }
    else {
        newData->previous = tail;
        tail->next = newData;
        tail = newData;
    }
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::insertHead(const T& theData) {
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = theData;
    newNode->next = head;
    head->previous = newNode;
    head = newNode;
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::insertTail(const T& theData) {
    Node* newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = theData;
    newNode->previous = tail;
    tail->next = newNode;
    tail = newNode;
}

//template <class T>
//void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::insertPosition(int pos, const T& theData) {
//    Node* prev = new Node;
//    Node* current = head;
//    Node* newNode = new Node;
//
//    for(int i = 1; i < pos; i++) {
//        prev = current;
//        current = current->next;
//    }
//    newNode->data = theData;
//    prev->next = newNode;
//    newNode->next = current;
//}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::insertPosition(int pos, const T& theData) {
    Node* current = head;
    int i = 0;
    while(current) {
        if(i++ == pos) {
            Node* newNode = new Node;
            newNode->data = theData;
            newNode->next = newNode->previous;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::display(std::ostream &str) const {
    for(Node* loop = head; loop != nullptr; loop = loop->next) {
        str << loop->data << "\t";
    }
    str << "\n";
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::deleteHead() {
    Node* old = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete old;
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::deleteTail() {
    Node* prev = nullptr;
    Node* current = head;

    while(current->next != nullptr) {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    tail = prev;
    prev->next = nullptr;
    delete current;
}

template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::deletePosition(int pos) {
    Node* prev = new Node;
    Node* current = head;

    for(int i = 1; i < pos; i++) {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    prev->next = current->next;
}

template <class T>
bool DoubleLinkedLists<T>::search(const T &x) {
    Node* current = head;
    while(current != nullptr) {
        if(current->data == x) {
            return true;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return false;
}



#endif /* DoubleLinkedLists_h */
```

Here is the main.cpp file to test the above implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "DoubleLinkedLists.h"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////// Double Linked List //////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    DoubleLinkedLists<int> obj;
    obj.createNode(2);
    obj.createNode(4);
    obj.createNode(6);
    obj.createNode(8);
    obj.createNode(10);
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"---------------Displaying All nodes---------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"----------------Inserting At Start----------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.insertHead(50);
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"-----------------Inserting At End-----------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.insertTail(20);
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"-------------Inserting At Particular--------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.insertPosition(5,60);
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"----------------Deleting At Start-----------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.deleteHead();
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"----------------Deleting At End-----------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.deleteTail();
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;

    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    std::cout<<"--------------Deleting At Particular--------------";
    std::cout<<"\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    obj.deletePosition(4);
    std::cout << obj << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    obj.search(8) ? printf("Yes"):printf("No");






    return 0;
}
```

**Update:**

This is what I have done so far, I am pass in the data into a new node and then link previous node with the next node. Although, the code runs but nothing actually gets inserted into a position so I believe it does not even go through the while loop. I am not sure what the problem is.

```
template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::insertPosition(int pos, const T& theData) {
    Node* current = head;
    int i = 0;
    while(current) {
        if(i++ == pos) {
            Node* newNode = new Node;
            newNode->data = theData;
            newNode->previous = newNode->next;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should try to draw a simple illustration of the nodes and how they connect to each other. and what need to happen when you insert the new Node.

Comment: Why are you allocating memory for the prev pointer? It should only be pointing to memory that has already been allocated. In the first iteration of your for-loop, that memory is lost track of and can not longer be accessed so that it can be freed. Otherwise it seemed like you were on the right track...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

```
    template <class T>
void DoubleLinkedLists<T>::insertPosition(int pos, const T& theData) {
    Node* current = head;
    int i = 0;
    while (current != nullptr) {
        if (i++ == pos) {
            Node* newNode = new Node;
            newNode->data = theData;
            // Let's do the wiring
            newNode->previous = current->previous;
            newNode->next = current;
            if (newNode->previous != nullptr) {  // If the node is inserted at the end
                newNode->previous->next = newNode;
            }
            current->previous = newNode;
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I am trying to completely understand it so let me see if I am almost there. For the newNode->previous = current we are setting a link of the previous node that will come before the new node that will come after it. Then for the newNode->next = current->next we are making a link for the new node to the node that will come after it. I am not sure if I understand the if statement for if the node is to be inserted at the end but I believe that is there in case the user of our class inserts at the end of the list. The only thing I completely do not understand is ...

Comment: the current->next = newNode that is after the if statement, what is that doing?

Comment: Also, I believe your code is slightly wrong, try testing it.

Comment: In a linked list each node needs to know which node comes after it, as you know. If you want to insert a node after `current` you need to tell `current` that the new node is after it now. That is what `current->next = newNode` does.

Comment: Why do you believe my code is wrong? I haven’t tested it and can't right now, but rereading it it seems fine (I might be overlooking something, though).

Comment: Your code runs but when I test it for insertPosition(1,10) it inserts 10 in the third place of the list.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx You were right. I hadn’t given much thought to that loop.

Comment: Hi again, I got a comment on your code from another post I made. The user stated that insertPosition may insert at the beginning or at the end, but fails to update head or tail. Do you know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi could you answer my question, I am sure if you saw my last comment.